# set encoded background image via css react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, background-image

I'm trying to set a background image to a container because I want to apply notification badges to the container. The problem is that no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the thing to actually render.

**React render:**

```
import bellImage from './assets/bell.png'

  render() {    
    return (
<div className="alertContainer" style={{background:"url("+ bellImage +")"}}>
                  </div>
)}
```

I've also tried `backgroundImage` and `background-image`. When I inspect the container, I do actually see the image encoded there. It just doesn't show up. Here is an example copy/pasted from chrome devtools:

**Chrome devtools styles tab:**

```
element.style {
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAYAAAD0eNT6AAAABmJLR…AAAAABAAAIAABAAAAAAgAAEAAAgAAAAAQAACAAAIAAfgGnR2N6Cb+0swAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
.header .alertContainer {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

Now if I go click on that background url link, it shows me the image!! So, it's getting in there. It just isn't getting displayed on the page for some reason.

The above is a minimal example of a much more complex component. If there isn't enough information here please just let me know. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: From the look of it, the problem is because you are outputting `<div className="alertContainer"...`, when you should be using `<div class="alertContainer"`. Try changing that and see if it fixes the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the image was so big I couldn't tell it was actually being rendered. I added the following to `style`:

```
"background-size": "40px 40px"
```

Set that value to whatever your container size is. In my case it was 40x40.